# Vim indentation for c++ templates?

Tags: c++, vim, templates, pretty-print, indentation

Does anyone have or know about vim plugin/macro/function that indents nicely c++ templates?

When I highlight template definition in vim .hpp/.h file and indent it with '=' I get something like this:

```
>     template <
>         class TFilter,
>               class TParser,
>               class TConsumer,
>               class TDataProcessor,
>               class TDataFeed,
>               class TSymbolMap
>                   >
>                   struct DataFeedTraits
>                   {
>                       typedef TFilter             Filter;
>                       typedef TParser<TSymbolMap> Parser;
>                       typedef TConsumer<Parser>   Consumer;
>                       typedef TDataProcessor<Filter,Consumer>  DataProcessor;
>                       typedef TDataFeed<Filter,DataProcessor,Parser,Ccnsumer> DataFeed;
>                   };
```

I think the cindent aligns the struct/class declaration with the closing bracket '>'.
I would like to end up with something like this, or similar, exact formatting does not matter, as far as it is formatted:

```
template <
    class TFilter,
    class TParser,
    class TConsumer,
    class TDataProcessor,
    class TDataFeed,
    class TSymbolMap
    >
struct DataFeedTraits
{
    typedef TFilter             Filter;
    typedef TParser<TSymbolMap> Parser;
    typedef TConsumer<Parser>   Consumer;
    typedef TDataProcessor<Filter,Consumer> DataProcessor;
    typedef TDataFeed<Filter,DataProcessor,Parser,Ccnsumer> DataFeed;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [identexpr](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27indentexpr%27) option to specify indent by evaluating an [expression](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#indent-expression) (i.e. writing a vim script function). This function should accept a string -- the line -- and return the number of spaces to indent. This gives you the flexibility to return an indent level for this template condition, or fall-back to [autoindent](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autoindent%27), [smartindent](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27smartindent%27) or [cindent](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27cindent%27) in normal, C-like situations.

[Here is an example that was created to handle the signals and slots extension of Qt.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_for_Qt_C%2B%2B) It demonstrates fall-back to the cindent function.

Answer (score 5):

My solution:

```
" Don't indent namespace and template
function! CppNoNamespaceAndTemplateIndent()
    let l:cline_num = line('.')
    let l:cline = getline(l:cline_num)
    let l:pline_num = prevnonblank(l:cline_num - 1)
    let l:pline = getline(l:pline_num)
    while l:pline =~# '\(^\s*{\s*\|^\s*//\|^\s*/\*\|\*/\s*$\)'
        let l:pline_num = prevnonblank(l:pline_num - 1)
        let l:pline = getline(l:pline_num)
    endwhile
    let l:retv = cindent('.')
    let l:pindent = indent(l:pline_num)
    if l:pline =~# '^\s*template\s*\s*$'
        let l:retv = l:pindent
    elseif l:pline =~# '\s*typename\s*.*,\s*$'
        let l:retv = l:pindent
    elseif l:cline =~# '^\s*>\s*$'
        let l:retv = l:pindent - &shiftwidth
    elseif l:pline =~# '\s*typename\s*.*>\s*$'
        let l:retv = l:pindent - &shiftwidth
    elseif l:pline =~# '^\s*namespace.*'
        let l:retv = 0
    endif
    return l:retv
endfunction

if has("autocmd")
    autocmd BufEnter *.{cc,cxx,cpp,h,hh,hpp,hxx} setlocal indentexpr=CppNoNamespaceAndTemplateIndent()
endif
```