# Vim indents C/C++ functions badly when the type and name are in different lines

Tags: c++, templates, vim, indentation

The following code snippets explain my problem well.

What I want:

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const vector<T>& v)
{
    ...
}

int
main()
{
    ...
}
```

What I get (notice the over-indentation before the function name):

```
    template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const vector<T>& v)
{
    ...
}

    int
main()
{
    ...
}
```

I have `set filetype plugin indent on` in my `~/.vimrc`.

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387792/vim-indentation-for-c-templates) but the answer in that looks like learning a new programming language. I am a vim fan, but not a vim expert. Isn't there a simpler solution?

Comment: This looks more like a bug you should report to vim than a question to answer here. See there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034510/bug-in-gvim-where-to-report

Comment: Even if it **is** a bug, this must have been faced by thousands of programmers. If it's a bug, i think it's ought to be fixed by now. :/

Comment: Did you try turning on `cindent`?  That works better with C-like languages in my experience.

Comment: What is the value of your `cinoptions`. Mine is: `g0,t0,h1s,i0` and I don't have the odd indentation you are observing. You may have a (ft)plugin that messes its value. You can see where it is changed with a `:verbose set cinoptions?`.

Comment: @Kevin: I thought `filetype indent` turns on `cindent` for C-type files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are seeing is the effect of `cino-t` (cinoptions setting t). You need to make sure conniptions contains `t0` to make the parameter flush with the left margin

From `:h cino-t`

```
                                            cino-t
    tN    Indent a function return type declaration N characters from the
          margin.  (default 'shiftwidth').

            cino=               cino=t0             cino=t7
                  int             int                        int
              func()              func()              func()
```

To do this you need to make sure that it is set for the cpp filetype. (`cindent` is turned on by the default cpp indent file)

I think just adding `set cinoptions+=t0` to your vimrc should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out and I just posted the answer myself which happened to be almost same as this one. :p

Answer (score 1):

Just as I guessed, this had a pretty simple solution! After motivating myself to read the `:help 'cinoptions-values'`, the following configuration was all that's needed to solve this particular problem.

```
:set cino+=t0
```

From the help text:

```
tN    Indent a function return type declaration N characters from the
      margin.  (default 'shiftwidth').

        cino=               cino=t0             cino=t7
              int             int                        int
          func()              func()              func()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try these indent options in .vimrc:
" Auto indent
set ai
" Smart indent
set si
" C-Style indent
set cindent